# Problem while solving exercise involving transitive sets

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am studying with Jech's Set Theory. In the Chapter 6, there is an exercise like this:

> Let $B$ be the class of all $x$ that are hereditarily in the class $A$. Show that
>   (i) $x \in B$ if and only if $\operatorname{TC}(x) \subset A$
>   (ii) $B$ is the largest transitive class $B \subset A$

Here $\operatorname{TC}$ means transitive closure and $B$ is the unique class satisfying $B = \{x \in A \mid x \subset B\}$. And we assume axiom of regularity(foundation).

I solved (i) for $\implies$ side. Trivially $\operatorname{TC}(\varnothing) = \varnothing \subset A$. Let $x$ be $\in$-minimal such that $x \in B$ and $\operatorname{TC}(x) \not\subset A$. Since $y \in x \in B \implies y \in B$, $\operatorname{TC}(x) = x \cup \bigcup_{y \in x}\operatorname{TC}(y) \subset A$ which is a contradiction. But I can't prove $\impliedby$ side.

For (ii), let $C$ be a transitive class $C \subset A$. Let $x$ be $\in$-minimal such that $x \in C \setminus B$. Then $x \subset B$ so $x \in B$, which is a contradiction.

I think the problem (i) has an error. Assume that (i) is right. Let $A$ be an ordinal. Then $A$ is transitive, so $\operatorname{TC}(A) = B = A$. Then by (i), $\operatorname{TC}(A) \subset A \implies A \in B = A$, which is a contradiction. Am I missing something?

Comment: $\subset$ sometimes doesn't mean proper subset in some books. So when $A$ is an ordinal, it is true that $\operatorname{TC}(A)\subseteq A$. Even $\operatorname{TC}(A)=A$. Also for (ii) note that $B$ may not be a set.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Thanks, edited. Yes $\subset$ doesn't mean proper subset so by (i) $A \in A$ Maybe an error?

Comment: Note that $A \subseteq \operatorname{TC}(A)$ and not  $A \in \operatorname{TC}(A)$.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri If (i) is true we can conclude $A \in B = A$.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right. It is wrong as it is stated. I think that your best bet for $(i)$ is: $x \in B$ iff $\operatorname{TC}(\{x\}) \subseteq A$. Note that the braces added here force $x\in A$, which we do need. And this resolves the contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we already quantify over $A$ in the very beginning of the exercise. Namely, we already required that $x\in A$. This renders the situation you describe impossible.

Having said that, I do agree that it would be clearer writing $\operatorname{TC}(\{x\})\subseteq A$.